# Find the second earliest time in a group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, group-by

Is there a way in pandas to find the second earliest time in a group? In this data frame, I want to find the second earliest time a buyer make at a particular branch and keeping the branch column after groupby buyers (for future count purposes).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({'Branch' : 'A A A A A A A B B C'.split(),
'Buyer': 'Carl Mark Carl Carl Joe Joe Joe Carl Mark Joe'.split(),
'Date':[datetime.datetime(2013,1,1,13,0),datetime.datetime(2013,1,1,13,5),datetime.datetime(2013,10,1,20,0),datetime.datetime(2013,10,2,10,0),datetime.datetime(2013,10,1,20,0),datetime.datetime(2013,10,2,10,0),datetime.datetime(2013,12,2,12,0),datetime.datetime(2013,12,2,14,0), datetime.datetime(2013,11,2,14,0), datetime.datetime(2013,11,5,14,0)]})
```

I could find the earliest time for each buyer at a certain branch as below:

```
df.groupby('Buyer').agg({'Date':'min', 'Branch':'first'})
```

I have trouble finding the second earliest. I have tried to use nsmallest(2) and last() to the the second earliest but that would include some of the first earliest if the buyer has only visited one branch. And I also would like to keep the branch column in the output table.

How can I find the second earliest time keeping the same format as the groupby I did above? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas `rank` function here.

```
In [23]: df
Out[23]: 
  Branch Buyer                Date
0      A  Carl 2013-01-01 13:00:00
1      A  Mark 2013-01-01 13:05:00
2      A  Carl 2013-10-01 20:00:00
3      A  Carl 2013-10-02 10:00:00
4      A   Joe 2013-10-01 20:00:00
5      A   Joe 2013-10-02 10:00:00
6      A   Joe 2013-12-02 12:00:00
7      B  Carl 2013-12-02 14:00:00
8      B  Mark 2013-11-02 14:00:00
9      C   Joe 2013-11-05 14:00:00
```

`df['rank'] = df.groupby(['Buyer','Branch'])['Date'].rank(ascending=True)`

```
print(df)
Out[31]: 
  Branch Buyer                Date  rank
0      A  Carl 2013-01-01 13:00:00   1.0
1      A  Mark 2013-01-01 13:05:00   1.0
2      A  Carl 2013-10-01 20:00:00   2.0
3      A  Carl 2013-10-02 10:00:00   3.0
4      A   Joe 2013-10-01 20:00:00   1.0
5      A   Joe 2013-10-02 10:00:00   2.0
6      A   Joe 2013-12-02 12:00:00   3.0
7      B  Carl 2013-12-02 14:00:00   1.0
8      B  Mark 2013-11-02 14:00:00   1.0
9      C   Joe 2013-11-05 14:00:00   1.0
```

This has attached the rank to every "Date" value for a particular **Buyer and Branch**. Now you can pick the desired rank you want.

So, 2nd earliest for a buyer and Branch would be something like this:
`df.query('rank == 2.0')`

```
Out[39]: 
  Branch Buyer                Date  rank
2      A  Carl 2013-10-01 20:00:00   2.0
5      A   Joe 2013-10-02 10:00:00   2.0
```